# SQL statement Select between sorted values

Tags: sql, sorting, between

I have a table of people. I want to sort the table by people's age and select those within a specific range age. This is what I tried:

```
SELECT *
from (SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY age DESC) as myalias
WHERE age BETWEEN 20 AND 25)
```

I do get results between these ages but there are not sorted out. Any suggestions?

Comment: it can be simplified like this SELECT * from people as myalias WHERE people_Age BETWEEN 20 AND 25 ORDER BY age DESC

Comment: You're doing things backwards. Simply: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ...`.

Comment: Do you really have two different age (age,people_age) fields on people table?

Comment: @ZekiGumus you are right I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  SQL queries return *unordered* sets . . . with one exception: if the outermost `select` has a corresponding `order by`.

So, the `order by` in the subquery has no effect.  Some databases do not even allow an `order by` in this case.  In others, it might *look* like the results are ordered, but changes to the data or environment could change that.

In your case, the subquery is unnecessary.  You probably know that but you should be writing:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM people p
WHERE p.people_Age BETWEEN 20 AND 25
ORDER BY p.age DESC
```